# Elevate current script with "-noprofile" argument

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm currently using the below code to elevate my current script by placing the code at the beginning of my script.  I would like to also include the "-noprofile" argument when elevating the script.  How do I include ***-noprofile*** at the ***$newProcess.Arguments*** line?

```POSH
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
$myWindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID);
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator;

if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{

    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)";
    #$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
    Clear-Host;

} else {

    $newProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
    $newProcess.Arguments = "& '" + $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'"
    $newProcess.WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
    $newProcess.CreateNoWindow = $True
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
    Exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `Arguments` property setting should work even if script path contains a space:

```
$newProcess.Arguments = "-NoProfile -Command `"& '$($script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)' `""
```

Another alternative:

```
$newProcess.Arguments = "-NoProfile -File `"$($script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)`""
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `-NoProfile` Argument like this:

```
$newProcess.Arguments = "-NoProfile -Command {$($script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)}"
```